# Extract a variable's value from a C++ program every 'x' seconds

Tags: c++

How to do this every 'x' seconds ? I have a client-server echo program, and I need to plot the throughput at every second in a graph. The program is compiled using `g++` in Ubuntu 14.04. I want to observe this program from outside and have it output the value in a file every `x` seconds. Source-code for client-side where I need to get the throughput every `1` second :

```
while(interval > 0){
  for(int i = 0;i < no_of_packets;i++){
    currentTime(buffer_rcvd);
    bytes_sent = sendto(socket_id, buffer_rcvd, sizeof(buffer_rcvd), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, addr_size);
    buffer_rcvd[bytes_sent] = '\0';
    bytes_rcvd = recvfrom(socket_id, buffer_rcvd, sizeof(buffer_rcvd), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, &addr_size);
    cout << "Received message on trip " << trip << " : " << buffer_rcvd << endl;
  }
  no_of_packets++, trip++;
  sleep(interval--);
}
```

Comment: If there are many possible good answers, I'd like to hear one of them atleast before the question is closed.

Comment: Can you patch and improve your programs' source code, or do you want to observe running *processes* from outside? Then, what compiler, what operating system, what compiler options? At last **why do you ask** ? Please **edit your question** to improve it a lot.

Comment: Clear enough ? @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: No bounds on that. @koalo

Comment: No bounds, you say? So *never* is within the required accuracy? ;-)

Comment: @Jarvis: no, you don't explain how the program is compiled (what compiler options) and how do you want to observe it from outside, and what program is it. Can you change your program? Can you show your source code (at least, as some URL to github, etc....) ?

Comment: Edited, @BasileStarynkevitch Compiled like this : `g++ -g client.cpp -o client`

Comment: @Jarvis: you really should explain your motivation and your program (we don't even know if you are writing a single server, or a client, or both) and edit a lot your question. You should add several paragraphs to it. If possible, show all your source code (probably thru some URL to some repository on http://github.com/ etc)

Comment: What do you need a "complete" code for here ? I just need to calculate `bytes_rcvd` every 60 seconds, and capture this value. The scope is limited to this loop only. @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: We don't understand what "capture the value" means. And I strongly believe you don't understand neither (and your confusion is much stronger than what you think). Who or what will "observe" that value, and how? The sentence "I want to observe this program from outside" needs at least an entire paragraph of explanation (and probably several ones)

Comment: You could also refine your question, to get it re-opened. Also, it is unclear at least to me, why just writing values to a file at intervals is not good enough for you.

Comment: I need to plot a graph of throughput versus time, and for that, I need a value every 60 seconds, being output-ed to some external file or something. @hyde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Your question is really unclear.

Here are some thoughts.

If you are coding your program and can modify its source code, you could just add some server abilities into it for instrumentation purposes. For example, you might add some HTTP server abilities: you'll use some HTTP server library like [libonion](http://coralbits.com/libonion/) and you could e.g. improve your code so that it serves on the `http://localhost:4567/status` URL and gives, as an HTTP response to every `GET http://localhost:4567/status` HTTP request, some JSON content with the appropriate status variable. BTW, this is **what I recommend** to do.

You could also have your program compiled with all debug options (e.g. compile it with `g++ -g -O`) and use some clever script which would: stop the process with SIGSTOP signal, start some `gdb -p` command, use `backtrace` and `print` gdb commands, and continue the process with SIGCONT

You might also consider [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). Maybe a clever use of [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) might be enough.

You could put important variables into a shared memory segment (use a pointer and some public `struct`, code an utility to read from that shared memory segment). Read [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) (and [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) for synchronization purposes).

You may think of other [inter-process communications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). See [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html), [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html) and read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

You could start an extra (instrumenting) thread which would log into some file, etc...

See also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) & [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

Perhaps your program should have a proper [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (see [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)...).

Otherwise, your quest is impossible: at runtime, C++ variables don't exist anymore (they are in registers, or in memory locations).

So depending on what you really want to do, it can be easy or impossible.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on your required accuracy, the platform and a lot more. Here are a few suggestions:

#### chrono

Put this at some place in your code that is executed often enough. However, this only works if you use C++11 (or later). And you should!

```
using namespace std::chrono;

/* Put this outside of your function or loop */
auto lastOutputTime = steady_clock::now();

/* Put this inside of your function or loop */
auto now = steady_clock::now();
if (now - lastOutputTime >= 60s) {
  auto throughput = getCurrentThroughput();
  std::cout << "Throughput: " << throughput << std::endl;
  lastOutputTime = now;          
}
```

#### clock()

Another option that would even work in C (apart from the output itself). However, as @Some programmer dude pointed out this method depends on the platform. Usually you measure CPU time with this and not wall-clock time. So it might or might not be sufficiently accurate for you.

```
/* Put this outside of your function or loop */
clock_t lastOutputTime = 0;
clock_t now = clock();

/* Put this inside of your function or loop */
if(now - lastOutputTime > CLOCKS_PER_SEC*60) {
  double throughput = getCurrentThroughput();
  std::cout << "Throughput: " << throughput << std::endl;
  lastOutputTime = now;
}
```

For using `clock()` you have to add the following to your header

```
#include <ctime>
```

#### time()

If you need wall-clock time and C++11 is not available, you can use `time()`. However, it only provides an accuracy of one second, which might or might not enough for you.

```
/* Put this outside of your function or loop */
time_t lastOutputTime;
time(&lastOutputTime);

/* Put this inside of your function or loop */
time_t now;
time(&now);
if(difftime(now,lastOutputTime) >= 60) {
  double throughput = getCurrentThoughput();
  std::cout << "Throughput: " << throughput << std::endl;
  lastOutputTime = now;
}
```

Comment: The `clock` function might not be useful since it's not standardized what it does. On some systems is is based of the wall-clock, on other it's a CPU-execution clock.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you are right, depending on the utilization of the system and if the program uses multiple threads it might drift a lot, but we do not know the required accuracy yet.

Comment: Where should I put this code if I'm simply looping over and over (and not a function which is invoked, hence no need of `static`) and updating the variable at the end of the loop ? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Just somewhere inside the loop, at the end would be a good choice. And you need the `static` or you have to put that line outside of the loop.

Comment: @AldwinCheung because it is not tagged C++11, but I will add more options.

Comment: Suppose my loop takes 120 seconds, so I would get two values, but since the calculatin is at the end of the loop, I will only 1 value, how to handle this ? @koalo

Comment: @AldwinCheung Ok, you convinced me :-)

Comment: @Jarvis Then just put it inside of your `for` loop.

Comment: @Jarvis If you are concerned that your `recvfrom` blocks for more than a minute, the measurement of throughput in intervals of one minute is meaningless anyway.